# Automate printing & dealing with large HTML files

Tags: php, performance, printing, large-files

I wrote a simple PHP application to create salary cheques for the company employees.
The interaction between db & app is nice, the data is cached & the performance is high enough. So, what's the problem?

I need to provide the ability to print the whole cheques by just one click for the end-user. printing such a large HTML file is not possible dealing not with browser crashes.

So, I appreciate if you have any solution/suggestion for **listing the cheques** and **printing 'em**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`FreePDF`](http://www.fpdf.org/), [`TCPDF`](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) and [`R&OS`](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/) PDF Generating libraries, could be more simplistic alternatives to Dav's solution.
Unlike the [`FreePDF`](http://www.fpdf.org/), [`TCPDF`](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) is supporting `UTF-8` encoding as well.

Comment: thanks these are all easier to work with than the PDF Object thing!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a PDF library to generate a PDF document that could be downloaded and then printed by whomever was doing the printing?

One option is the PHP [PDF object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php), some other options are also listed in the comments on that page.

Comment: thank you Dav. I'll work on it. is there any UTF support available using this to generate PDF?

Comment: Considering the existance of functions like http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-utf16-to-utf8.php I would assume the answer is yes, though I haven't used that particular functionality myself.